# Save select statement for later

Tags: sqlite

I'm often creating interesting SQL statements for my SQLite database.

Is it possible to save these statements for later use?

I'm looking for something more clever than copying to a text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

Then you can re-use it later with:

```
SELECT * from my_view;
```

Not sure if this is what you're asking?